# Euler's formula for non-planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Could anyone please provide an example of non-planar graph, that corresponds to Euler's formula:
$$v - e + f = 2$$

or show that there is no such a graph?

Comment: What does $f$ mean when $G$ is non-planar?

Comment: I was given a task to prove the planarity of an arbitrary graph by using this formula. I am not quite sure how to measure faces in that case, so that's why I am trying to find out the way I was supposed to do it.

Comment: @DánielG. That is basically the answer. If you post it as an answer, I will upvote.

Comment: @Peter I've deleted my comment and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Euler's formula can only be used to prove that a graph is non-planar. To prove planarity, one usually either finds an actual plane drawing or shows that the graph contains no $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ minors.