# Proving Planarity of a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I know the condition to be planar graph is that $E \leq 3V − 6$, so if we have a graph where the number of edges is smaller than $3\cdot (vertices) − 6$, can we say its planar? If not, how would I go about proving that a graph is planar? (other than using Kuratowski's Theorem)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949457/eulers-formula-for-non-planar-graph?noredirect=1#comment8143821_3949457

Answer (score 2):

The [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) is non-planar and has $10$ vertices and $15$ edges.  The inequality $E\leq 3V-6$ is not a "condition for a graph to be planar."  It is a property of planar graphs.  That is, any planar graph will satisfy this inequality, but as the example shows, there are non-planar that satisfy it also.